# amCharts date-time value issue, can not set hh:mm time

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, gantt-chart

I'm new on amCharts to create ganttCharts and the others. I'm trying to create a gantt chart and set some time value to each column. So I can create with these lines;

```
{
        "category": "Planned", 

        "segments": [   {
         "start": 8,
            "duration": 9,           
            "color": "#46615e",
             "task": "Order"
        } ,{
         "start": 18,
            "duration": 1,           
            "color": "#46615e",
             "task": "Order"
        } ,{
         "start": 20,
            "duration": 1,           
            "color": "#46615e",
             "task": "Order"
        } 
 ]
    }
```

But for start value, instead of 8,18,20, I want to write 08:18, 18:22, 20:25 and something like these.

But it does not work with these values.. do you have any idea? I will share all code below.

```
   <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
    #chartdiv {
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
    }                                                                   
    </style>

    <!-- Resources -->

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/gantt.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <!-- Chart code -->
    <script>
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
        "type": "gantt",
        "theme": "dark",
        "marginRight": 70,
        "period": "hh",
        "dataDateFormat":"YYYY-MM-DD hh:nn",
        "balloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN",

        "columnWidth": 0.5,
        "valueAxis": {
            "type": "date",
             "parseDates": true,
              "minPeriod": "mm"
        },
        "brightnessStep":  0,
        "graph": {
            "fillAlphas": 0.5,  
            "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:11px'>[[category]] -> [[task]]</span>",
            "labelText": "[[task]]",
            "labelPosition": "left",
             "labelOffset": 0,
        },
        "rotate": true,
        "categoryField": "category",
        "segmentsField": "segments",
        "colorField": "color",
        "startDate": "2018-10-02 00:00", 
        "startField": "start",
        "endField": "end",
        "durationField": "duration",
        "dataProvider": [ {
            "category": "",
            "segments": [   {
             "start": 7,
                "duration": 17,           
                "color": "#fff" 
            }  ]
        }, {
            "category": "Column A", 

            "segments": [   {
             "start": 8,
                "duration": 9,           
                "color": "#46615e",
                 "task": "Order"
            } ,{
             "start": 19,
                "duration": 1,           
                "color": "#46615e",
                 "task": "Order"
            } ,{
             "start": 21,
                "duration": 1,           
                "color": "#46615e",
                 "task": "Order"
            } 
     ]
        },  {
            "category": "Column B",
            "segments": [ {
                "start": 8,
                "duration": 8,
                "color": "#8dc49f",
                "task": "Order"
            }, {
                "start": 17,
                "duration": 2,
                "color": "#8dc49f",
                 "task": "Order"
            }, {
                "start": 20,
                "duration": 2,
                "color": "lightblue",
                "task": "Order"
            } ]
        }],
        "chartCursor": {
            "cursorColor":"#55bb76",
            "valueBalloonsEnabled": false,
            "cursorAlpha": 0,
            "valueLineAlpha":0.5,
            "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
            "valueLineEnabled": true,
            "zoomable":false,
            "valueZoomable":true
        } 
    } );
    </script>

    <!-- HTML -->
    <div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: use strings `'08:18'` etc

Comment: I did, but did not work

Comment: `but did not work` - what happened instead of working? did it change all the clocks in your house to GMT time? did it shoot your dog? "it did not work" is clear, if it did work, you would have said it did ... please, try a tiny bit of debugging for yourself

Comment: {
        "category": "Column B",
  "segments": [ {
            "start": '08:18',
            "duration": 8,
            "color": "#8dc49f",
            "task": "Order"
        }, {
            "start": '18:18',
            "duration": 2,
            "color": "#8dc49f",
             "task": "Order"
        }
First segment is starting on 22:00,
Second Segment : 06:00
so I can not figure it out why it happens like this. Sorry for short description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values mapped by the startField and endField only accept numeric values. If you want to set times, you have to use dates through startDateField and endDateField.

```
  "startDateField": "start",
  "endDateField": "end",
  "dataProvider": [ {
     // ...
    "segments": [ {
      "start": "2016-01-01 08:18",
      "end": "2016-01-11 18:18",
```

Check [this example](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart-dates/). While it only uses dates, you can provide a datetime that matches your dataDateFormat.

Comment: thanks it worked and set data to the chart.. Do you know that getting data from .json and setting to the chart? I do not find many resources about amChart unfortunately..

Comment: The JSON you have to attach to the chart needs to match the format set by the static examples (array of objects). You can modify the chart's dataProvider property then call validateData to update to chart, or use the [dataLoader](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/). There's a gantt example for you to look at as well.